# Is the attack on titan manga complete?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I finished season 2 of attack on titan but I don't know how far ahead the manga goes in comparison to the show.

Comment: a quick [wikipedia search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan) will answer the question in the title of your question. would post an answer now but your follow up question about how *"far ahead the manga goes in comparison to the show"* i can not answer myself

Answer (score 2):

No, the manga is still being published.

If you'd like to start reading it, [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/40922/17758) asks about where the second season of the anime leaves off in relation to the manga.